# Deserialzise JSON with only parts of needed model information in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, deserialization

do I always need to create a model for an incoming JSON and then deserialize the JSON to it or is there a way to loop through the JSON file, check specific properties and add additional information?

Here is why I ask:

In my project I have two classes "region" and "country". Inside "region" is the nested class "country"

```
enter code here
public class Region`enter code here`
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string ISO3166Alpha2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string ISO3166Alpha3 { get; set; }
  }
```

Now I have an incoming JSON which has the country and region information which i need but without Ids or any other required information.

So do i need to create a new model, deserialize the JSON and then use that new model to create my "region" and "country" model or is there a better way of doing this?

```
{
  "regions": [
    {
      "country": "France",
      "region": [
        "Bordeaux",
        "Burgundy",
        "Beaujolais",
        "Champagne",
        "Loire",
        "Alsace",
        "Rhône",
        "Provence",
        "Languedoc-Roussillon",
        "Jura"
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "Italy",
      "region": [
        "Piedmont",
        "Barolo",
        "Barbaresco",
        "Tuscany",
        "Veneto",
        "Friuli-Venezia",
        "Giulia",
        "Abruzzo",
        "Sicily",
        "Lambrusco"
      ]
    }
}

´´´
Thanks a lot :)
```

Comment: Your JSON appears to have a class that has a string and a List<string> which doesn't match up with your class objects.

Comment: One way of doing it, is to create a `class Region` and in that table just have a property called `RegionName` or something, then another property called `CountryId` and it would be a foerignkey for the `Region` class. Then add whatever proeprties are needed in the `Country class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly find below the way to achieve that as stated by the docs. kindly visit this link https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm but however my solution is shown below.[image]

```
 var json1 = @"{
        'regions': [
          {
                    'country': 'France',
            'region': [
              'Bordeaux',
              'Burgundy',
              'Beaujolais',
              'Champagne',
              'Loire',
              'Alsace',
              'Rhône',
              'Provence',
              'Languedoc-Roussillon',
              'Jura'
            ]
        },
          {
            'country': 'Italy',
            'region': [
              'Piedmont',
              'Barolo',
              'Barbaresco',
              'Tuscany',
              'Veneto',
              'Friuli-Venezia',
              'Giulia',
              'Abruzzo',
              'Sicily',
              'Lambrusco'
            ]
    }]}";
 var definition = new { regions = new[]{new {country = "" , region = new string[]{ }  } }};
            var customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);
            Console.WriteLine(customer1.regions);
            foreach (var item in customer1.regions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.country);
            }
```